# Jquery conflict while using telerik extention and kendo ui side by side

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, telerik, kendo-ui

I am developing an MVC 3.0 razor application. In my project, we are using jQuery Version 1.7.1. For telerik extention, we are using jquery ver 1.6.4. We are also using Kendo UI grid in some part of the project, that requires jQuery Version 1.7.1. We placed the script in the layout page in the following order.

```
 <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo.all.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
   @(Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar().jQuery(false)
    .DefaultGroup(
        grp =>
        {
            grp.Add("jquery-1.6.4.js");
            grp.Add("jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.js");
            grp.Add("telerik.common.min.js");
            grp.Add("telerik.upload.min.js");
            grp.Add("telerik.window.min.js");
            grp.Add("telerik.draganddrop.min.js");
            grp.Add("telerik.grid.min.js");
            grp.Add("telerik.grid.editing.min.js");
            grp.Add("telerik.grid.filtering.min.js");
            grp.Add("telerik.grid.reordering.min.js");
            grp.Add("telerik.grid.resizing.min.js");

            grp.Add("telerik.datetimepicker.min.js");

            grp.Add("telerik.treeview.min.js");

        }))
```

In this case all the telerik extentions controles and related client events(Example: OnSelect event of telerik panel bar) will work but kendo ui grid control doesnt load data. But if we are commenting jQuery version 1.6.4 inside Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar(), kendo ui will load the data but telerik extention client events will not work. Please provide a solution.

Comment: Have you tried noConflict mode of jQuery?

Comment: I have provided jQuery.noConflict() in kendo ui grid view page. But it does not load the data. Issue remains exist.

Comment: I dont know about Kendo much.noConflict of jQuery will help you to release $ and substitute it with something else.So if kendo uses $ as well then noConflict can help you.Otherwise you have some different conflict.

Comment: Why can't they both use the newest version of jQuery ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all - you cannot use multiple jQuery on the same page and expect the widgets to work. Each time you load a jQuery the data and events are cleared from the memory which means the widgets which were registered will not be available anymore.

I would suggest you to update your MVC extensions (classic ones) to the latest version which I can see in the demo site it is using jQuery 1.7.1. Also the current version of the KendoUI framework is version 1.7.1 it is still not 1.8+.